# How to get the IC numbers of the logisim items

Tags: logisim

`Logisim` makes it very easy for user to intuitively manipulate and edit the components already provided to achieve the circuit he wants. But there is no information about the actual IC numbers of those components which is present in `Proteus`. I could just do a google search, but there are multiple implementations for the same component and thus different IC numbers.

> Is there any way I could find out the IC numbers of `logisim` components?

**EDIT** Just to clarify, I'm looking for a way find out the IC numbers of the components. For example, what is the IC number of ROM used in Losigim? I can change the data and address width arbitrarily and that will change the actual IC I can use in the real world. How can I get the number of that IC?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. It might be helpful to illustrate your question with screenshots or other kinds of examples. Currently it is a little difficult to understand your problem.

Comment: For most of the simple logic gates, they are based upon the more common versions of the 7400 series parts. However, the simulation isn't anything like an accurate emulation of the actual parts. It's just a "mostly" behavioral one. So there really isn't any real parts to associate. A NAND gate, for example, might be a 74LS00 which can sink \$8\:\text{mA}\$ or it might be a 74LS38 which can sink  \$48\:\text{mA}\$. And there are other families, like "S". So how can you pick? The simulator is behavioral. No specific part for each gate.

Comment: I'd also recommend that you use [Digital](https://github.com/hneemann/Digital), instead. Much better and it is currently being supported and updated, as well. It does actually include 7400 series family parts, too. So you can know what you are placing down, if you want to know.

Comment: @jonk, yeah, you're right. Logisim does actually present an easy to use but abstract view of the circuit. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @klaus (I meant the 74LS37, earlier. My mistake.) Regardless, I think you really should consider wasting your learning time on Digital rather than Logisim. Both are great tools. But Logisim is dead and Digital is better in every possible way. It's really worth the investment in time (and it's a lot like Logisim, so you don't lose much of the learning you've already gone through.) I won't even bother with Logisim, anymore. Are you considering the idea of building something? (Say, a CPU???) I did so in 1974. So I can really wish you the best of luck, if that's your direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard components of Logisim are **not** modelled after specific ICs. So there are no IC numbers.

It is rather the other way around: You can (to some degree) model a certain IC with a component in Logisim. You might like to search for a Logisim library which contains models of ICs.

There are far too many technologies like TTL, CMOS, FPGA, CPLD, and so on. How should a learning tool like Logisim support them all? It is more about learning digital logic on an abstract level.